# Are resource_semaphore_query_compile waits causing 100% CPU on server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Of late, the cpu usage on the db server is consistently at 100%. Even at 2 in the night when there is almost no traffic on the website and the load is negligible.

While trying to find the root cause, I see a lot of waiting tasks with wait type `resource_semaphore_query_compile`? All of these have started appearing lately in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`

```
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x006E9E28  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x006E8F28  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x006E94C8  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x008DC988  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x008DD798  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x006E9C48  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x594364D8  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
0x006E9978  97  0   0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE    0x027AAAC0  0x006E8C58  NULL    NULL    resourceWait
```

Why is this happening all of a sudden when nothing has changed? Also, the server 'self healed' itself yesterday, but the problem is back today? How to debug and fix this

Comment: I also see in perfmon that processes blocked keeps varying between 0,1,2 16 and 24

Comment: What is session_id 97 doing???  A RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE wait is typically when there is a memory-intensive query that isn't able to get the requried memory for query execution or optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked active tasks too, in addition to waiting ones? Check [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for offenders with high `cpu_time` values. Look in [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for queries with high `total_worker_time`.

An explanation for what is happening could be that a plan changed to result in a very CPU intensive execution plan with a large memory requirement (eg. hash joins, sorts). Parallel table scans and joins on non-aligned partitions come to mind... Few queries execute but they consume high CPU (the query exec and query stats views will reveal this). The queries require a large memory grant and cause other instances of the same query to block on the resource grant. A look in [`sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms366321%28v=sql.105%29) will reveal if this is true. Solution would be to address the plan stability, perhaps deploy [plan guides](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916034714/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/02/19/plan-guides-plan-freezing-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx).

Comment: Would it also be worth looking into whether the plan cache is bloated by single-use plans and considering `optimize for ad hoc workloads`?