# What's Scalar Operator in the plan?

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a doubt. What means this Scalar Operator in the print below?

I've been investigating our database cause we have severals RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE . I've seeing a lot of queries using this in the joins which costs more. Is it normal or it's not a coincidence?

[image: scalar]

Thanks,

Armando

Comment: I think your wait is a sign of memory pressure or too many compilations happening at the same time. That operator is most likely harmless (it just produces a scalar value). Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/support_sql_france/archive/2012/02/07/sql-server-compilation-gateways-and-resource-semaphore-query-compile.aspx), [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15723/418), [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293620.aspx) or [this](http://mssqlwiki.com/2012/10/12/what-is-resource_semaphore_query_compile/).

Answer (score 1):

When you're looking to track down the root cause of RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE waits, the plan operators you want to pay attention to are most commonly

- Sorts
- Hash Joins
- Hash Match Aggregate

That's because it's a memory wait. Specifically, queries asking for memory, and SQL Server not having it available for them to start running.

If you're on a more recent version of SQL Server (2012 SP3, 2014 SP2, 2016+), you can use a free tool like [sp_BlitzCache](http://firstresponderkit.org) (full disclosure, I'm a contributor) and run it to sort your plan cache by memory grant.

```
EXEC sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'memory grant'
```

But fair warning, if you're hitting a bunch of that wait, there's a good chance your plan cache is wiped out from the memory pressure.